# What's up with Vic?

Tags: glitch

In the TV series *Glitch*, we see several people returning from the dead.

We see Vic, a police officer,

> getting in a car accident and seemingly [returning from the dead](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/147670/19561).

Afterwards, he behaves very strange. He searches for the doctor and the risen, whom he seems to know a lot about, sometimes even more than they know themselves.

> He rekills Maria by breaking her neck.

And he threatens the other risen.

Most of the risen, especially those that have been dead longer, have some difficulty remembering their past lives. Vic on the other hand, seems to remember fine but to have a complete change of character instead.

- **Why is he after the other risen?**
- **How does he know so much about them?**
- **Why did he have such a change of character?**

---

*Yes, these are several questions, but they are closely related, so I opted to ask them in one question.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This becomes a bit clearer in the second season. Vic, and later

> Phil and Sarah

have died and immediately come back to life, their bodies having been taken over by unknown entities, who are to correct "the aberrations": rekill the risen.

What they are exactly, is not yet explained by the end of season 2.