# Has Vic indeed risen?

Tags: glitch

In the TV series *Glitch*, we see several people returning from the dead. Most of them, especially those that have been dead longer, have some difficulty remembering their past lives.

In the second episode, "Am I in Hell?", Vic has a car accident near the cemetery the *risen* came from. We're made to believe he has now risen too.

In a later episode, doctor Elishia McKellar confirms that he has died and immediately come back to live during the accident, although it's unclear how she knows that.

Vic shows a complete change of character after his accident.
Also, he seems to heal at extraordinary speed.

**Has Vic risen?**